# Cumulative include records in stored procedure output based on a number of bit parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

How do I implement a SQL Server stored procedure which responds correctly to "floating" parameters?

Suppose there is a table `Students`. Some of them play basketball (active), some attend fine-arts classes (creative). The rest is doing nothing.

I implemented two columns of datatype `bit` to distinguished them.

I want to have a single but sorta *overloaded* stored procedure which allows me to **cumulatively include** active and creative students in query results.

Assuming the parameters definition

```
create proc myproc
    @is_active bit = 0,
    @is_creative bit = 0
as
```

the procedure must be able to execute in the following ways:

```
exec myproc
exec myproc 1,
exec myproc 0, 1
exec myproc 1, 1
```

Dealing with many `AND`s in the `WHERE` clause as well as with the `UNION` does not bring the desired results because of many complex `IF`s and ugly coding-style in general.

I wonder if there is a neat and eclectic query to actually *switch on and off* the desired parameters and vary output.

Table:

```
Name              PlaysBasketball      AttendsArtClasses
========================================================
Mark                    1                       0
Debbie                  0                       1
John                    0                       0
Steve                   1                       0
Pat                     0                       1
Bill                    0                       0
Tiffany                 0                       0
Sam                     1                       1
Jackie                  0                       0
```

Sample stored procedure executions:

As you see from the table above John, Bill, Tiffany and Jackie have no interests in life. So a simple SP query (with no params) shall include 4 of them in the resultset.

Then I want to *switch on* the bit and to select ball players in addition to John, Bill, Tiffany and Jackie. So I `exec myproc 1` and here comes the resultset:

- John
- Bill
- Tiffany
- Jackie
- *Mark*
- *Steve*
- *Sam*

Then I want to switch on both flags: `exec myproc 1, 1` and I should get the complete gang in my resultset.

Comment: Your structure is wrong. You should probably have a separate table with a row for each studentid/activityid.

Comment: What do you mean "cumulatively include" students?  Can you edit your question to provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have updated the post with sample scenarios. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that what you really want is this:

```
create proc myproc
    @is_active bit = NULL,
    @is_creative bit = NULL
as
```

And then a `where` clause that looks like:

```
where (@is_active_bit is null or @is_active_bit = is_creative) and
      (@is_create_bit is null or @is_creative_bit = is_creative)
```

This assumes that you have columns corresponding to `is_active` and `is_creative` is your table.

EDIT (after update to question):

I think you want:

```
create proc myproc (
    @is_active bit = 0,
    @is_creative bit = 0
)

where (PlaysBasketball = 0 or @is_active_bit = 1 and PlaysBasketball = 1) and
      (AttendsArtClasses = 0 or @is_creative_bit = 1 and AttendsArtClasses = 1);
```

Comment: Thank you, Gordon. This is exactly what I want.

Comment: Cannot stop to enjoy this query... ;)