# How to use a bit parameter to filter records on more than one condition inside a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameter-passing, bit, logical-operators

I tend to use bit values as parameters of a stored procedure to include/exclude the records. To filter the query on columns of datatype `bit` is now easy as I know the techniques from this SO post:
[Cumulative include records in stored procedure output based on a number of bit parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25217884/cumulative-include-records-in-stored-procedure-output-based-on-a-number-of-bit-p)

There are some cases however, when I need to use a bit parameter to filter *composite values* with more than one condition.

Here is the example:

[image]

There is a `bit` parameter passed to the stored procedure.

```
myproc 0
```

The above call just returns some records except the blue-highlighted ones.

Once in a week I need to call

```
myproc 1
```

to include/accumulate those records `WHERE ((Delta = 0) AND (PriceCurrent = PriceMin))`. In the example above the dataset must include both blue-highlighted records.

For some reason the code

```
AND ((Delta = 0 AND PriceCurrent = PriceMinMin) 
     OR (@incl_min_price = 1 AND
         NOT (Delta = 0 AND PriceCurrent = PriceMin)))
```

does not work for me. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**:

Please disregard *my logic* whatever it is. I just want to filter records passing a single parameter of bit value. In other words, `myproc 0` must return

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE --several conditions separated by AND/OR
```

whereas `myproc 1` must produce the above **and**

```
AND ((Delta = 0) AND (PriceCurrent = PriceMin))
```

Comment: You may consider posting the query before `AND` too; it is hard to guess your logic with the provided information

Comment: @techspider my logic is not relevant to the question. All I want to know is how to filter the complex request `WHERE (Delta = 0) AND (PriceCurrent = PriceMin)` passing bit value as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Three options out of many possible variants:

```
create table #tmp (ID int identity(1,1), PriceMin int, PriceCurrent int, Delta as PriceCurrent - PriceMin)

insert #tmp 
values (10, 12), (10, 10), (10, 15), (9, 12), (3, 3)

declare @bit bit = 0

select  *
from    #tmp
where   (@bit = 1 or 
            (Delta <> 0 or PriceCurrent <> PriceMin)
        )

select  *
from    #tmp
where   (@bit = 1 or 
            (not(Delta = 0 and PriceCurrent = PriceMin))
        )

select  *
from    #tmp
where   @bit = 1 or @bit = case when Delta = 0 and PriceCurrent = PriceMin then 1 else 0 end
```